# Mysql function sub-queries return issue

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_nth (x int)
RETURNS int DETERMINISTIC
    RETURN
        SELECT MIN(m.salary) 
        FROM
            (SELECT * 
             FROM salaries 
             ORDER BY salary DESC
             LIMIT x) AS m;
```

I'm trying to fetch an nth salary from the table, that's why I have written this function, but it shows an error and I can't figure out why:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select min(m.salary) from (select * from salaries order by salary desc limit x) a' at line 3

This subquery is working fine as individual query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using a subquery as a value in an expression, you need to enclose it in parentheses:

```
return (select min(m.salary) from (select * from salaries order by salary desc limit x)as m);
```